# Hibernate: how to create a relation with two tables?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design, orm, relationship

I have a three tables:

**table**

```
-----------
|id       |
-----------
|data_type|
-----------
|data_id  |
-----------
```

**table_data_a**

```
----------
|id      |
----------
|table_id|
----------
```

**table_data_b**

```
----------
|id      |
----------
|table_id|
----------
```

*data_type* is a `enum('data_a', 'data_b')`;

*data_id* is a relation to *id* fields of tables **table_data_a** or **table_data_b**

1. It is correct approach to creating of the relations?
2. How to describe this relations in Hibernate?

Comment: It will be better, if you explain on a real example, what you are going to store in the tables.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion -

Ans1) There is no need to make relationship between these tables(association or inheritance) as data_id can act as id of both the table(table_data_a and table_data_b).Its better to take it as String or int as per your datatype in db , and make separate call to both tables for search.

Ans2) Mapping through Association [refernce](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_or_mappings.htm)

Mapping through inheritance [refernce](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-inheritance-mapping-tutorial)